# Given an integer M, what is the largest float C such that (int)C < M?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm mapping a large number of floats to ints. All floats are in range [0;1] and the ints should be in range [0, M) where `M = 1 << k`, e.g. 256.

I care about even distribution, so I cannot use something like `round (f * 255)`, which leaves the first and buckets with half the capacity.

So naively, one would do this:

```
int i = (int)(f * M);
```

Since this fails for f = 1.0 (leading to i = M instead of M - 1), we need to cover that separately:

```
int i = min (M - 1, (int)(f * M));
```

Instead I would like to simply do something like

```
int i = (int)(f * C);
```

where C is a float constant smaller than M that guarantees the strict inequality `(int)(f * C) < M` for all f in range [0;1].

Of course, we could simply set `C = M - 0.001f` and be done with it. But let's suppose we want to do it the right way. What exactly is C, if arbitrary integer widths rather than just 8 bit are involved? In other words:

**Given an integer M > 0, what is the largest float C such that `(int)C < M`?**

Comment: Are you asking for c or c++? They are different languages and may have different solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but could [`std::next_after`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) help?

Comment: Why do you think your truncation approach (by casting to `int`) will give you a more uniform distribution than `round()`ing would?  Either way, you have to deal with the fact that the representable `float` values are twice as dense in the first half of your interval as in the second half.

Comment: If the range you want is `[0, M]` then why is `int i = (int)(f * M);` a problem?

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, typo. M is excluded.

Comment: you are trying to map a half open interval to a closed one, is that on purpose?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The first bucket holds values in 0 to 0.5 and the following one holds 0.5 to 1.5, so it is not an even distribution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Primarily C++. next_after could be the solution, but it was not 100% clear to me if it would always work with the cast or possibly round up sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given an integer M, what is the largest float C such that (int)C < M?

It will be `std::nextafterf(M, 0)`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that casting the result to int rounds down?

Comment: @mafu Yes (towards zero). The standard says: `A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
that is, the fractional part is discarded. `

Comment: Thank you. I really overthought this problem, and you showed a clean and easy way.